# Naming an AWS EC2 Security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-security-group

Using the AWS dashboard, and under Security Groups, I see them listed under the following columns:

```
Name......Security Group ID.....Security Group Name.....VPC ID.   Description.....Owner......
```

The AWS PHP SDK v 3.xx has a createSecurityGroup method under the Ec2Client, that allows the creation of security group. I am using it, but I can't figure out how to set the "name" value (first column). The docs do not describe how to do this.

I tried adding a Name parameter (to mimic the CLI), but it did not work.

```
$Ec2Client = new Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'us-east-1,
    'profile' => 'default']);


$SecGroupParams = ['Name' => 'My Security Group','Description' => 'My Security Group', 'GroupName' => 'my_security_group', 'VpcId' => 'vpc-xxxxxx']

Ec2Client->createSecurityGroup($SecGroupParams);
```

The group is create, but the name is empty (just like when it's created using the dashboard).

Any idea how to do this?

Picture of dashboard:

[image: Image of main security groups dashboard]

[image: Picture of associated group's tags]

Comment: It's working now but the AWS docs are misleading

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the security group creation is successful the way I am doing it, but the Name is not created. I did try using Tags, but the Name column is NOT a tag.

Comment: It is a tag. You can check that in AWS Console. Go to your SG, and check it tags, and create a tag with Name key.

Comment: You're talking about something different. I've been able to create tags along, but in the Dashboard, this "Name" is a column name. I will edit my question and add pictures

Comment: Yes. The "Name" as a column name, is taken from tags. So create a tag called "Name", and this will populate the  "Name"  column on your screenshot.

Comment: I've already tried that, and it does not work

Comment: It does work, I assure you. Maybe you have to make new question and explain what actions are you doing in AWS console to create that tag. Whatever you are doing in AWS console with tags, must be incorrect.

Comment: How did it go? Still tagging does not work?

Comment: OK, I am not trying to do this via the console. I am trying to do it via the API using the AWS PHP SDK. There is no option to create an entry in the Name column. It can be done via the CLI, but not the PHP SDK.

Comment: `CreateTags` does not work as I wrote in my answer? Maybe you are using `CreateTags` incorrectly?

Comment: NO, I am not using CreateTags for this

Comment: Why not? You have to use it to create the tag "Name".

Comment: How did it go? Still can't create the tag?

Comment: I managed to create the Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do with `'Name' => 'My Security Group'` will not work, as the `Name` should be a **Tag** with key called "Name". So you have to tag your security group. This is done using [CreateTags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-ec2-2016-11-15.html#createtags) in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

you should mention the Name in tags.

```
$SecGroupParams = ['Name' => 'My Security Group','Description' => 'My Security Group', 'GroupName' => 'my_security_group', 'VpcId' => 'vpc-xxxxxx', 'Tags' => [['Key' => 'Name', 'Value' => 'My Security Group']]]
```